# Laravel 5 - routing

Tags: php, laravel-5

The following code that I've written on my `routes.php`. When I open my `localhost` it loads with no problem. But when I change my url to `localhost\contact` browser says **`404 Not Found`**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('contact', function(){
    return 'Contact';
});
```

So what could be the problem here. Can any one help me.

**P.S :** I've not change any thing after installation. I've only add that route line on the `routes.php`.

Comment: Is your Apache mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: @tliokos from where do I do that ?

Comment: What is you Operating System? Are you using WAMP or something similar?

Comment: Try in your console `apache2ctl -M` to see if rewrite_module is in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable rewrite module.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Check in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for the `<Directory var/www>` section and change

`AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

and then restart you apache again

Comment: I edited the answer. Can you try to change AllowOverride?